# Find caching DNS server?

Tags: cache, domain, domain-name-system

Is there any way to find out which servers, on the way on DNS routing, are caching records, and for how long? I'm on a iMac with Leopard.

The reason I ask this, is that I've made some DNS changes to a domain name yesterday, and it's 30 hours later and still I'm not getting any changes. But through a few proxies, we saw the changes already 4 hours after the change, which would be normal.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for testing purposes you can edit your /etc/hosts file and add lines like:

```
127.0.0.1 my.new.domain.org
12.13.14.15 my.other.domain.org
```

If it's in a general sense (you just launched a new website) then you are stuck. ISP doesn't like to show lot of their internals.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the current TTL sent by your caching resolver using `dig`:

```
$ dig +nocmd your_domain.com A +noall +answer
your_domain.com        86331    IN    A    192.168.1.1
```

The second column of the output is the current TTL in seconds. Repeat the query after a few seconds to verify it reduces.